# How to add string to autofield/primary key using Django

Tags: django

I have created a model with few fields like name, type, date and Request_Id

Whenever I insert a new record in database, I want to append a string eg: REQ to id (primary key/autofield)  for request_Id field.

EG: REQ_1, REQ_2, REQ3

Any suggestions to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to store REQ_ in each record if you can append this value to the id later in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to define a custom primary_key field. 
And on model save, you can append `REQ_` before it

Something like that (didnt test it)

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  
        if not 'REQ_' in self.id:  
            self.id = 'REQ_'+self.id
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `save` method will execute every time the model is saved so it will result in an `id` like `REQ_REQ_REQ_...`

Comment: Now the problem is that you need to define the first iteration to get the first `id`. I suggest checking if the object has an `id`, if does not has, creating something like an `uuid`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Request(models.Model):
    Request_Id = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

create a function which can create your Request_Id as you want.
where key = "REQ_"

```
def create_request_id(key):
    num = Request.objects.all().count()
    return key + str(num)
```

now you can store that id as a "Requested_Id"

Comment: I think this can lead to a concurrent problem which results in trying to create two or more `Requests` with the same `Request_Id`

Comment: if you want a unique id you can use "date" instead of num. But i think you can create one Requests at a time. Do i know what is your approach thank you.

Comment: The problem with the concurrency is that you can have two users which can push the button to create the object at the same time. My approach will be using just a `id` or a `uuid` as a primary key an then create a property on the object to append the `REQ_` string

Comment: It will never happen if two user push button at the same time but your server take one request first then other.

Comment: `dt = datetime.now()
    
     return key + str(dt.year) + str(dt.month) + \
               str(dt.day) + str(dt.hour) + str(dt.minute) + \
               str(dt.second) + str(dt.microsecond) + \
               str(rand4Digit())` you can use it for id

Comment: You can not guarantee that one request will be processed before the other. If you have one server and only with one worker maybe but I will not guarantee. But for a production site, you will probably want many workers per server and at least two servers in HA. Instead of using date I would use a `uuid` with are by definition unique.